# Cannot access Chart from within Event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events

I am trying to run the subroutine DrawPoint from within an event and it does nothing. I can call this even from other places in the code and it works fine.

```
Public Sub DrawPoint(X As Double, Y As Double, Optional SeriesRef As Integer = 0)
    'Draws a point on the graph given X + Y coordinates
    MainForm.Chart.Series.Item(SeriesRef).Points.AddXY(X, Y)
End Sub
```

When run from within the com_DataRecieved event the command does nothing. I have even tried adding the `MainForm.Chart.Series.Item(0).Points.AddXY(X, Y)` to the com_DataRecieved Event itself and it still doesn't work or error or do ANYTHING wrong except for not display on the graph! This is extremely strange to me. 
Here is the com_DataRecieved Subroutine:

```
Public Sub com_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles com.DataReceived
    'Handles recieving COM data
    Dim line As String = com.ReadLine 'For storing the read line
    'If the first character is a number then...
    If Asc(line(0)) < 58 And Asc(line(0)) > 47 Then
        'Console.Out.WriteLine("DEBUG: COMDATA: " + line)
        Dim lineSplit As String() = line.Split(",")
        Dim X As Double = Convert.ToInt32(lineSplit(0))
        Dim Y As Double = Convert.ToInt32(lineSplit(1))
        Console.Out.WriteLine("DEBUG: COMPARSEDDATA: " + X.ToString + ";" + Y.ToString)
        DrawPoint(X, Y)
        'MainForm.Chart.Series.Item(0).Points.AddXY(X, Y)
        DrawPoint(13, 5)
    Else
        'Write other lines to console as debug datas
        Console.Out.WriteLine("DEBUG: COMDEBUG: " + line)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to see any other sourcecode for the project you can click(to Github) [here](https://github.com/RX14/SWRChart/).

EDIT: I added a piece of code that lists the number of chart points on the graph to Console and it came up with some weird information that makes no sense. it is really difficult to explain but when I add points really quickly (over COM) the number of points seems to go up but they seem to remove themselves from the list too. I had one time where i was adding the points slowly and i had 1,1,10,1 when the additions were ~2s apart! As i stated before this is incredibly confusing to me!

Comment: is the datareceived event firing in another than the Main thread? if so try to use `Me.Invoke(Sub() DrawPoint(13,5))` instead of the the simple DrawPoint statement.

Comment: @Jens I am not conciously running the event in another thread and Me. I have called InvokeRequired but it returns False and when I try to invoke i get `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.`

Comment: How exactly do you call the Invoke? Is this from a module and you type something like frmMain.Invoke(...)? The problem would then be that you do not really call the frmMain-Object (therefore the No-Handle-Error). You should then make a Sub() in frmMain.vb like `Sub DoDrawPoint(X as Double, Y as Double) <lf> Me.Invoke(Sub() DrawPoint(X, Y)) <lf> End Sub`. In the event you would then call `frmMain.DoDrawPoint(X, Y)` .The `Me` references the real window object. The implementation of calling stuff from frmMain (which is really just the class, NOT the object) is a bit confusing from time to time.

Comment: @Jens I have tried your DoDrawPoint sub but it still returns the same error! I suggest you see the code at ^github^ and see what ive done yourself :D I may not be able to answer quickly over Christmas because i'm on a extremely slow laptop! :(

Comment: @Jens Still need help on this one...